# Image is not displaying in exact place in table tr td using tcpdf php

Tags: php, html-table, tcpdf

I am trying to add image in tr td using php tcpdf. 
But sometime images are going another td.

```
<tr><td><img width="80px" src=image.jpeg'/></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to be sure the image fits in your td else you will have an overflow and tcpdf does not handle this correctly

Comment: there is too much space for image in td, but still it shows in another place.